# AWS Cloudwatch alarm for fluctuating datapoints

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am monitoring a Fargate service on ECS and want to know when containers are bouncing a lot (come up, fail healthcheck, get killed by ECS and a new one gets scheduled and does the same)

I replicated the scenario I'm interested in and using the "Sample count" aggregation for CPUUtilization from ECS I can see this graph:
[image]

The value in an ideal world would be 1 but as we can see here ECS schedules a new container to replace the unhealthy one and that gets killed eventually and we see this bouncing behavior

I would like to set up a Cloudwatch alarm for this. When the value fluctuates a lot from the ideal value in a short period of time but I can't quite figure out if this is possible. Maybe with some metric math but I can't quite get it. I also looked into Anomaly Detection and I think that would work but it incurs extra cost that I don't think is warranted

Just looking to set off an alarm if value bounces around multiple y axis points in let's say a 5 minute time frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this with metric math:
`RUNNING_SUM(ABS(DIFF(myMetric)))`

This will return a rolling sum of all the absolute changes in the metric for your period. You can then create an alarm based on this, adjusting the desired period and threshold.